# Objective c property setters aren't working

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Ive now identified a problem in a few diff classes in my iPhone Coco2d game, my first Objective-c go. My setters don't seem to be working! If I try access property after setting it's either NULL (if to Stringed) or I get a fatal bad access exception, I must be doing something wrong, heres my code:

```
@interface Character : CCNode 
    {
        CCSprite* sprite;
        int width;
        int height;
    }
    @property (retain) CCSprite* sprite;
    @property int width;
    @property int height;
@end
```

and implemntation:

```
@implementation Character

@synthesize sprite;
@synthesize width;
@synthesize height;

-(id) init
{
    if((self=[super init])) {
        [self setSprite :[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"character.png"]];
        [self setWidth:28];
        [self setHeight:28];
        NSLog(@"About to try get height...");
        NSLog([self height]); //bad access exception
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not returning `self` from the `init` method. Copy & paste mistake?

Comment: New to Objective-C? Please start with ARC and save yourself from a world of pain. See: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/
Also, you should prefer dot notation: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/06/crazy-objectivec-dot-notation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a poorly formatted log statement

```
NSLog(@"Height :%d", [self height]);
```

`NSLog` looks for a string to print, you've given it an int which can't be changed to an object

Comment: THANKYOU! That fixed it all :D What does that @ do?

Comment: The `@` tells you a string is following. Height is no string, NSLog expects a string, so the only solution is (as James said) correct formatting.

Comment: Strings in objective-c are prefixed with the `@` to distinguish them from c-strings `@"Hello" != "Hello"`